# Jest testing hook state update with setTimeout

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, settimeout, enzyme

I'm trying to test unmount of a self-destructing component with a click handler. The click handler updates useState using a setTimeout.

However, my test fails whereas I'm expecting it to pass. I tried using jest mock timers such as advanceTimersByTime() but it does not work. If I call setState outside setTimeout, the test passes.

*component.js*

```
const DangerMsg = ({ duration, onAnimDurationEnd, children }) => {
const [isVisible, setVisible] = useState(false);
const [sectionClass, setSectionClass] = useState(classes.container);

function handleAnimation() {
    setSectionClass(classes.containerAnimated);
    let timer = setTimeout(() => {
        setVisible(false);
    }, 300);
    return clearTimeout(timer);
}

useEffect(() => {
    let timer1;
    let timer2;
    function animate() {
        if (onAnimDurationEnd) {
            setSectionClass(classes.containerAnimated);
            timer2 = setTimeout(() => {
                setVisible(false);
            }, 300);
        } else {
            setVisible(false);
        }
    }

    if (children) {
        setVisible(true);
    }
    if (duration) {
        timer1 = setTimeout(() => {
            animate();
        }, duration);
    }
    return () => {
        clearTimeout(timer1);
        clearTimeout(timer2);
    };
}, [children, duration, onAnimDurationEnd]);

return (
    <>
        {isVisible ? (
            <section className={sectionClass} data-test="danger-msg">
                <div className={classes.inner}>
                    {children}
                    <button
                        className={classes.btn}
                        onClick={() => handleAnimation()}
                        data-test="btn"
                    >
                        &times;
                    </button>
                </div>
            </section>
        ) : null}
    </>
);
```

};

export default DangerMsg;

*test.js*

```
it("should NOT render on click", async () => {
    jest.useFakeTimers();
    const { useState } = jest.requireActual("react");
    useStateMock.mockImplementation(useState);
    // useEffect not called on shallow
    component = mount(
        <DangerMsg>
            <div></div>
        </DangerMsg>
    );
    const btn = findByTestAttr(component, "btn");
    btn.simulate("click");
    jest.advanceTimersByTime(400);
    const wrapper = findByTestAttr(component, "danger-msg");
    expect(wrapper).toHaveLength(0);
});
```

**Note**, I'm mocking useState implementation with actual because in other tests I used custom useState mock.

Comment: Hi, exact same issue, using `testing-libarry` instead of Enzyme. More broadly the issue is to simulate the rerender of the component after state change. For me `rerender` does not seem to work.

Answer (score 15):

Not using Enzyme but `testing-library/react` instead so it's a partial solution. The following test is passing as expected:

```
  test("display loader after 1 second", () => {
    jest.useFakeTimers(); // mock timers
    const { queryByRole } = render(
      <AssetsMap {...defaultProps} isLoading={true} />
    );
    act(() => {
      jest.runAllTimers(); // trigger setTimeout
    });
    const loader = queryByRole("progressbar");
    expect(loader).toBeTruthy();
  });
```

I directly run timers but advancing by time should give similar results.

Comment: Just FYI: `useFakeTimers` has an optional argument `implementation` for choosing between the legacy implementation (jest's own ) and modern implementation (sinon's fake timers). For faking timers such as the ones used by lodash debounce, use `modern`. More info can be found [in the docs](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/jest-object#jestusefaketimersimplementation-modern--legacy). Also, in this [issue thread](https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/3465#issuecomment-623393230).

Comment: should  `jest.runAllTimers();` be inside an act(), I figured it wouldn't have to.