# Jest test case PASS - but line uncovered - REACT-Typescript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, unit-testing, jestjs

I dont know how to coverup lines inside try/block's setTimeout().

my test case is passed, but still don't understand why in ICOV report show lines are not covered.

simple logic onClicking submit btn in REACT

```
const saveData = async (e: any) => {
  const body = {
    //....
  };
  setShowSpinner(true);
  const isRollNumberExist = await checkRollNumberExist(data?.studenRollNumber);
  if (!isRollNumberExist) {
    try {
      await saveStudentInfo(body);
      setTimeout(() => {
        setShowSpinner(false);
      }, 2000);
    } catch (error) {
      setIsLoading(false);
      setShowErrToaster(true);
    }
  } else {
    setShowErrToaster(true);
  }
};
```

conditionally rendering spinner

```
 { isLoading && <CustomSpinner isLoading={loading}/>}
```

test case **PASS** but **FAILED** to **COVER LINES inside TRY/CATCH and ELSE** part

```
it("should spinner for 2 sec", async () => {
  jest.useFakeTimers(); // mock timers
  jest.spyOn(mockService, "saveStudentInfo").mockResolvedValue(undefined);
  jest.spyOn(mockService, "checkRollNumberExist").mockResolvedValue(false);
  const { getByText, getByTestId, queryByTestId } = render(
    <StudentEnrollmentFrom />
  );

  const submitButton = getByText("Submit");
  fireEvent.click(submitButton);
  await waitFor(() => {
    expect(getByTestId("stdForm")).toBeInTheDocument();
  });
  act(() => {
    jest.runAllTimers(); // trigger setTimeout
  });

  jest.useFakeTimers(); // mock timers
  const { queryByRole } = render(
    <CustomSpinner {...defaultProps} isLoading={true} />
  );
  jest.advanceTimersByTime(2000);
});
```

referred [SO -1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52633843/jest-unit-test-settimeout-not-firing-in-async-test) [SO -2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60688975/jest-testing-hook-state-update-with-settimeout) [SO -3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69032600/mocking-settimeout-with-jest) but still unable to fix my issue.

Need help

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue comes from combining Async/Await with fakeTimers, that can give quite the headache and I wouldn't recommend it, unless you have to. Here is a much better answer than I could give: [Jest: Timer and Promise don't work well. (setTimeout and async function)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52177631/jest-timer-and-promise-dont-work-well-settimeout-and-async-function)

Some other issues that are apparent:

- you do not have to call useFakeTimers multiple times, once faked they remain faked till you call useRealTimers.
- RunAllTimers and advanceTimersByTime are both used to trigger timeout, you only need one, and I don't believe it should be wrapped in act().

You do a new render at the end of your test, after which you don't expect anything, why? If you want to test something else make a new test, remove it here.

```
it("should spinner for 2 sec", async () => {
  jest.useFakeTimers(); // mock timers
  jest.spyOn(mockService, "saveStudentInfo").mockResolvedValue(undefined);
  jest.spyOn(mockService, "checkRollNumberExist").mockResolvedValue(false);
  
const { getByText, getByTestId, queryByTestId } = render(
    <StudentEnrollmentFrom />
  );

  const submitButton = getByText("Submit");
  fireEvent.click(submitButton);

//Since you are using fakeTimers, do you still need the await waitFor? if you mock resolves for all the promises, can't you get away with removing it. Making your test synchronous, or maybe adding Promise.resolve().
  await waitFor(() => {
    expect(getByTestId("stdForm")).toBeInTheDocument(); //I assume this is a spinner? I'd recommend using a better name. 
  });
  jest.advanceTimersByTime(2001); // add a millisecond to be save
  
  expect(queryByTestId("stdForm")).toBeNull(); //or something else, but I feel you are missing some expects here if you are ending your test with advancing timers or rendering something, than what is the point, tests should end with expects.
});
```

I am curious to see what you end up with. Like I said, these timers can be quite tricky.